# Symfony FormType - Select on ManyToOne impossible

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to create a new FormType for my Symfony Application. I have a ManyToOne field :

```
    // Grower.php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoryGrower", inversedBy="growers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $category;

    // CategoryGrower.php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Grower", mappedBy="category")
     **/
    private $growers;

    // GrowerType.php
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'FermierMalin\Bundle\GrowerBundle\Entity\CategoryGrower',
            'choice_label' => 'label',
            'group_by' => 'parent',
        ));
```

But the select in HTML code is empty :

```
<div>                
<label for="fermiermalin_bundle_growerbundle_grower_category" class="required">Category</label>        
<select id="fermiermalin_bundle_growerbundle_grower_category" name="fermiermalin_bundle_growerbundle_grower[category]" required="required">
</select>
</div>
```

In my DB, I have some datas :

```
ID, label, parent
1,Fruits,Maraichers
2,Légumes,Maraichers
3,Vin,Boissons
4,Jus,Boissons
```

Comment: Can you give the whole class (Grower and CategoryGrower) with getters / setters and constuctors ?

Comment: @HubertLcorche [Grower](http://pastebin.com/65kQ6NLb), [CommentGrower](http://pastebin.com/KcPsgw5B)

Answer (score 1):

I made mine like this

Entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FamebitBundle\Entity\Price")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="price_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $price;
```

FormType

```
->add('price', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'FamebitBundle\Entity\Price',
            'property' => 'label',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
        ))
```

Twig view

```
{{ form_row(form.price) }}
```

This worked for me :)